# NEED SQL QUERY FOR DESIRED OUTPUT

Tags: sql-server

Below is the sample data which gets filled into sql server database from PLC machine. DATETIME, CYCLETIME(TIME TAKEN TO PRODUCE THAT MATERIAL) AND SHIFT

[image]

There are 3 shifts in company A(6:30Am to 2:30PM), B(2:30 to 10:30), C(10:30 to 6:30AM).Only C shift sample data is shown above

when i take C Shift count, my query should take next day data also till 6:30AM time. Where as A shift should take current day data starting from 6:30Am to 2:30Pm.Where as B shift should take current day data starting from 2:31pm to 10:30PM.

QUANITY shown below IS COUNT OF ROWS in each shift.

DESIRED OUTPUT 1: SHIFTWISE DATA
[image]

DESIRED OUTPUT 2: DAYWISE DATA
[image]

Comment: Why are you SHOUTING? What have you tried so far to solve the problem, and why didn't it work? Please don't supply your data as an image either; we can't use it. Provide your sample data as tabular formatted `text`, or as DDL and DML statements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick trick that should work is to just shift the times back by six and a half hours so they align midnight to midnight.

```
SELECT CAST(dateadd(minute,-390,[DateTime] AS date), [SHIFT], COUNT(*) AS QUANTITY
FROM [YourTable]
GROUP BY CAST(dateadd(minute,-390,[DateTime] AS date), [SHIFT]
```